# New element symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to design a new element symbol. How can I add the red line and blue line (different codes `\myin` `\mynotin` ) to my code?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\h {1.3ex} % cup and cap height
\def\w {1.2ex} % cup and cap width
\def\lw{0.12ex} % cup and cap line width
\def\spp{0.7269ex} % space before and after

\newcommand{\myinn}[1]
{
  \hspace{\spp}
  \tikz[line width=\lw,line cap=round,rotate=#1,baseline=-0.4ex]
  {\draw (-0.5*\w,0.5*\h) -- (-0.5*\w,0.5*\w-0.5*\h)
  arc (-180:0:0.5*\w) -- (0.5*\w,0.5*\h);}
  \hspace{\spp}
}
\newcommand{\myin}{\myinn{270}}
\begin{document}
\[\myin\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: hm, $\in$, $\notin$? or should be  symbol elements colored as shown on image?

Comment: No. color is not a problem @zarko

Comment: why you like to draw this symbols if they already exist? I do not understand your intention :-(

Comment: I use in different fonts @Zarko

Comment: Which fonts you use (that not support basic math symbols)?

Comment: @Zarko ı use helvet font and i also use MnSymbol package

Comment: @Zarko it supports but the symbol stays small

Comment: Than scale them up.

Comment: I know you are right. I would like to know this code too. Can you help me ?@Zarko

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear, what is your problem. Exercise with drawing symbols as pictures (not recommended for use in documents) or to have symbols appropriate size.

Anyway, the standard use of your symbols:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
text $\in$, $\notin$
\end{document}
```

gives good match sizes of symbols and text:

[image]

If this is not your problem/concern, please edit your question and clarify, what you like to have.

Comment: I want to re-encode the element symbol. I wrote some of the code but I couldn't create the middle line.

Answer (score 1):

This produces your desired effect:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\len}
\settowidth{\len}{$\notin$}
\newcommand{\mynotin}{\mbox{
{\color{blue}$\notin$}%
$\hspace{-\len}${\color{red}$\in$}%
$\hspace{-\len}${\color{black}$\subset$}%
}}
$a \mynotin\ S$
```

[image]